# Filter script tags into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an example markup:

```
<p><span style="color: blue;">Yes this one now</span></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>The main configuration value is this</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>!</p>
<p>enable</p>
<p>configure terminal</p>
<p>server name <span style="color: red;">Server Name</span></p>
<p>enable secret <span style="color: red;">Server Pass</span></p>
<p>no ip domain-lookup</p>
<p>ip domain name <span style="color: red;">region</span>.google.com</p>
<p>!</p>
<p><br></p>
```

I want to write a Javascript to filter all the span tag data into 2 different arrays. One for when color is red and the other one when color is blue. But I am an unable to do that can someone help me out with this? I am trying wiring the JS code but my solution fails.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve] even if it fails. We can't debug what we can't see. Also, how is this related to React? [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) along with [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get elements

```js
const html = `<p><span style="color: blue;">Yes this one now</span></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>The main configuration value is this</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>!</p>
<p>enable</p>
<p>configure terminal</p>
<p>server name <span style="color: red;">Server Name</span></p>
<p>enable secret <span style="color: red;">Server Pass</span></p>
<p>no ip domain-lookup</p>
<p>ip domain name <span style="color: red;">region</span>.google.com</p>
<p>!</p>
<p><br></p>`

const blueArray = html.match(/(?<=<span style="color: blue;">)(.*?)(?=<\/span>)/g)

console.log(blueArray)

const redArray = html.match(/(?<=<span style="color: red;">)(.*?)(?=<\/span>)/g)

console.log(redArray)
```